# Extract a specific key's value from a JSON file

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

I've got a huge JSON that looks like this. Sample

```
{
  "Key": "4fa21496-3534-4480-8405-a0f7699a915e",
  "FirstName": "XX",
  "XX": "Liggins",
  "City": "Dallas",
  "RegionCode": "TX",
  "RegionName": "Texas",
  "Country": "United States",
  "Latitude": "32.783060",
  "Longitude": "-96.806670",
  "TimeZone": "America/Chicago",
  "IsCASL": false,
  "Updated": "2018-02-28T07:32:28",
  "HQCompanyName": "IHOP",
  "Position": "Server",
  "Level": "General",
  "Department1": "General",
  "DecisionMaker": false,
  "EmailAddress": "YYY@gmail.com",
  "EmailValidationStatus": "AcceptAll",
  "EmailValidationDate": "2018-02-10T03:02:07.1692141+00:00",
  "HQCompanyId": "XX2f37e171e26112cb",
  "Experience": [
    {
      "HQCompanyId": "XX2f37e171e26112cb",
      "Title": "Server",
      "Level": "General",
      "Department1": "General",
      "DecisionMaker": false,
      "Start": "2014",
      "End": "2015",
      "EmailAddress": "XXX@gmail.com",
      "SecondaryCompanyId": "10407780-c062-40c9-8783-110aa931a9c5",
      "Updated": "2018-08-31T23:52:31.663147Z"
    },
    {
      "HQCompanyId": "128ce753-6a72-4028-8a17-d76a1c53b22e",
      "Title": "XX",
      "Level": "General",
      "Department1": "General",
      "DecisionMaker": false,
      "Start": "May 2015",
      "End": "December 2015",
      "Duration": "7 months",
      "Updated": "2018-08-31T23:52:31.663147Z"
    }
  ],
  "Education": [
    {
      "Name": "XX",
      "Degree": "XX or equivalent",
      "Start": "2004",
      "End": "2008"
    }
  ],
  "SearchUrl": "https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=XX+X",
  "SourceList": []
}
```

I want to retrieve all email addresses from a json file, basically the `user@domain` in `EmailAddress: "user@domain"` so it looks like this,

```
YYY@gmail.com
XXX@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 14):

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/), a proper JSON parsing tool:

```
$ jq -r '..|.EmailAddress? //empty' infile.json
YYY@gmail.com
XXX@gmail.com
```

try it online: https://jqplay.org/s/yjkKkCxecg

---

from the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/):

> `--raw-output / -r`:
> With this option, if the filter's result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than
> being formatted as a JSON string with quotes.

> **Recursive Descent: `..`**
> Recursively descends `.`, producing every value.
> [...]
> In the example we used `..|.foo?` to find all the values of object keys "foo" in any object found "below" `.`.

> **Optional Object Identifier-Index: `.foo?`**
> Just like `.foo`, but does not
> output even an error when `.` is not an array or an object.

> **Alternative operator: //**
> A filter of the form `a // b` produces the same
> results as `a`, if `a` produces results other than `false` and `null`.
> Otherwise, `a // b` produces the same results as `b`.
>
> This is useful for providing defaults: `.foo // 1` will evaluate to `1` if
> there's no `.foo` element in the input.

> **`empty`**
> `empty` returns no results. None at all. Not even `null`.